# How can i write sum query with linq to sql to calculate sum of the nchar field value?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm beginner in `linq to sql` and in my database number save the `nchar` field with this shape:
[image]

i can't change the count column field type to number,because database is not to me,must be calculate sum of the count field,i write this query:

```
var query=(from p in behzad.MYTEMPDB
          where p.fileid.trim()=dropdown1.text() && p.name=dropdownlist2.text()
      select p).toArray();
int sum=0;

foreach(var item in query){
    sum+=Convert.toInt32(item.COUNT);
}
```

can i use other query for that purpose?thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop to calculate sum. You can write this as below

```
int sum = behzad.MYTEMPDB.where(p => p.fileid.trim()=dropdown1.text() 
          && p.name=dropdownlist2.text()).sum( p => Convert.ToInt32(p.Count));
```

Comment: thanks my friend it's work.